# Signed measures and poset inequalities

Tags: measure-theory, simplicial-complexes

Consider a triangulated ball $D$, and assume that $\omega$ is an assignment of real weights
to the simplices of $D$, including the empty one, such that for every maximal simplex $F$ and every simplex $G$ in $F$, we have

$\sum_{x \in [G,F]} \omega(x) \ge 0.$

Is it true that

$\sum_{x \in D} \omega(x) \ge 0$?

Here $[G,F]$ is the interval of $G$ to $F$, that is, all simplices containing $G$ and contained in $F$.

Edit: for Cohen-Macaulay complexes (which are more general than balls) the answer is no. Raman Sanyal showed that the dual linear program is infeasible for an example of nonpartitionable complexes. I will leave it open since my original question is unsolved, but that provides an indication.

Accepting Raman's answer even though the question for disks is open

Comment: An equivalent reformulation: can we assign to each pair $(F,G)$ of a maximal simplex $F$ and a simplex $G$ in $F$ a nonnegative weight $u(F,G)$ such that $\sum_{x\in [G,F]} u(F,G)=1$ for all $x\in D$?

Comment: Thanks Ilya. Let me add that I also don't know this to be false for any Cohen-Macaulay poset.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: your summand does not depend on $x$.

Comment: @RichardStanley yes that is the point. You sum over those pairs $G$ and $F$ whose interval contains $x$

Comment: You can think of this as a fractional partitioning

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: it might be worth pointing out that you are using duality of linear programming, or more precisely Farkas' lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma)

Comment: As you mention, Karim, the problem (in Ilya's dual reformulation) is a kind of fractional partitioning: specifically, if we have a partitioning then we can set $u(F,G)=1$ if $F$ and $G$ are the bottom and top elements in an interval in our partitioning, and $0$ otherwise. Since the question of whether every triangulated ball is partitionable appears to be open, this would suggest the answer to your question is also not known. (Of course in theory it might be possible to show that a fractional partitioning always exists without showing a non-fractional partitioning does.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SAGE says it's not true for non-partionable but Cohen-Macaulay complexes. Problem of finding $\omega$ can be reformulated as a LP feasibility problem (as explained by Ilya) and for an example from "A non-partitionable Cohen–Macaulay simplicial complex" the dual problem was infeasible.

Comment: Thanks. Can you add the weight that provides the counterexample?

Comment: Checked as well, seems correct!

Comment: I'm confused as to how this answers the question as literally stated. The example under discussion is not a triangulated ball, is it?

Comment: @SamHopkins I would assume that the example is realizablo as such. But, anyway, 
 it would be much more pleasant if such details appeared here, in order not to urge each reader to find those  by themselves.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: I doubt this, because if you look at the paper (at least, the arXiv version https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.04279), you'll see "Question 4.1. Is every simplicial ball partitionable?"

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov I agree that it would be nice to have an explicit understandable example, but due to the nature of the construction it is quite large. I will leave the question open for now.